# How to get all the radio buttons with the same id?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web form that have 5 radio button with the same id.

How can I catch all the radio buttons in a vector from JavaScript?

Comment: An id is actually required to be unique, hence the name.

Comment: you mustn't have multiple elements with the same ID, it will break your JavaScript. The `name` attribute is for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use different ids or different names for html elements. Also jquery helps you on this subject.

```
$(':radio')
```

it helps you to select all radio elements on the page. You can do what you want with using Jquery.

here is the jquery source: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Using same ID for more than one element on page is incorrect! use `name` attribute to group these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Element identifiers: the id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.
The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element (which may be verified by an SGML parser).

The id attribute has several roles in HTML:

As a style sheet selector.
As a target anchor for hypertext links.
As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g. for identifying fields when extracting data from HTML pages into a database, translating HTML documents into other formats, etc.).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id